# Trigger Wordpress Image Gallery Via Button/Link

Tags: wordpress, button, hyperlink, gallery, lightbox

I want to open a default Wordpress gallery in a lightbox with a button or link and hide the gallery thumbnails on the page. How can I achieve that?

Gallery shortcode: `[gallery ids="55,67"]`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
<style>
    .hiddengallery{
        display:none;
    }
</style>



<button class="showgallery" >click here</button>

<div class="hiddengallery"> 
    // add lightbox code here
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery ids="55,67"]');?>
</div>


<script>
    jQuery(document).on("click",".showgallery", function (){
        jQuery(".hiddengallery").show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this just hides/unhides the thumbnails of the gallery. You will need to click again on one of the thumbnails to show an image inside the default lightbox. What I try is to simulate a click on the first gallery thumbnail with a button.

Comment: I solved this by simulating a click on the first thumbnail of the hidden gallery: `jQuery(".gallery-item:first-of-type > .gallery-icon > a").trigger("click");`